# TinyMCE strips HTML, although I have told it not to

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am struggling with TinyMCE and custom tags. We are building a custom CMS that is using the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor. This are my settings:

```
 tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        width: "200",
        theme: "advanced",
        cleanup_on_startup: false,
        trim_span_elements: false,
        verify_html: false,
        cleanup: false,
        convert_urls: false,
...
```

So, in one page I have to add this tag through the source editor:

```
 <gcse:searchresults-only queryParameterName="search"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

but, the editor is stripping it. I tried adding this rules:

```
extended_valid_elements: "gcse:searchresults-only[*]",
custom_elements: "gcse:searchresults-only"
```

and it was possible to add the tag, but if it's not nested in any other tag. If I wrap that tag in a div element, it did strip it (the gcse tag) leaving the div empty.

Question: how can I disable TinyMCE from stripping ANY of the tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the tinymce cleanup isn't possible since version 3.4. You will have to set valid_elements and valid_children accoring to your needs.